# Difference between asymptotically AdS and asymptotically locally AdS spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, definition, holographic-principle, anti-de-sitter-spacetime, asymptotics

In the literature, there is often a distinction made between spacetimes that are asymptotically or asymptotically locally some other spacetime. For example, in holography, referring to some spaces that are asymptotically Anti-de Sitter (AAdS) or asymptotically locally Anti-de Sitter (AlAdS). What is the difference between both? When some space in AlAdS but not AAdS and how can we distinguish them?

Comment: Do you mean asymptotic vs asymptotically local?

Comment: Which literature? Which pages?

Comment: Throughout https://escholarship.org/content/qt11p1957k/qt11p1957k_noSplash_07aa6afc325920f18445764cdf0a4e08.pdf